# Android - holder returning null from recyclerView adapter item position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I want to get the view from a given item position in my recyclerView, but the holder is always coming null and I cant figure out why.

```
                        Rect toRect = new Rect();
                        selectedPostTagsAdapter.addPostTag(postTag);
                        selectedPostTagsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        for (int i = 0; i < selectedPostTagsAdapter.getItemCount(); i++) {
                            RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = rvSelectedPostTags.findViewHolderForItemId(selectedPostTagsAdapter.getItemId(i));
                            if (holder != null) {
                                View viewX = holder.itemView;
                                viewX.getGlobalVisibleRect(toRect);
                            }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons that [`RecyclerView.findViewHolderForItemId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#findViewHolderForItemId(long)) might return null.

First, it will *always* return null if your `RecyclerView` does not have stable ids. You can call `rvSelectedPostTags.setHasStableIds(true)` to turns this feature on. Note, however, that you actually have to have logically-stable ids if you want to use this. All that means is that a given data item should always return the same id, regardless of its position.

Second, it will return null if you pass the id of an item that is not currently laid out inside the `RecyclerView`. So if you can currently see items #5-#12, but you want the `ViewHolder` for #200, it's not going to work.

Comment: I already set  selectedPostTagsAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);, but I keep getting the holder as null. I've read the second possible reason for the problem, but I still don't get it.

Comment: Your adapter is backed by some sort of data model, usually a list. The RecyclerView will only show some of that data at any one time. Your data model could have thousands of items while the RecyclerView only shows ten of them. Any id for an item that isn't on screen would return null from `findViewHolderForItemId`